# check whether the record exists in database when user logging using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

```
I want to check whether the user is existed when trying to logging in using ajax and if not existed allow three attempts and block. if record exists redirect to another page

<input type="hidden" id="attempt" value="3">
<p id="footer"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
while(1)
{
    var d_name=prompt("username","");
    if(d_name != "")
    var d_password=prompt("password","");
    var attempt = document.getElementById("attempt").value;
    if(d_name != "" && d_password != "")
    {
$.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" +"",
  data:{
   d_name:d_name,
   d_password:d_password,
  },
  success: function(result) {
    if (d_name+d_password=="result[d_name]result[d_password]") 
        {
    alert('success');
    location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>");
},
error: function() { 
  alert("error");
}
 });
   break;
        }       
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("attempt").value = attempt -1;
            alert("You have left "+(attempt-1)+" attempt;");

            attempt = attempt - 1;
            if( attempt == 0)
            {
                alert('you are blocked'); 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
my database have values as d_name:done, d_password: done, so i have the result as name:done and password:done. i want to check the user giving input with database values.
```

my output is 
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["doc_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["d_name"]=> string(4) "done" ["d_password"]=> string(4) "done" } } 
All i want is to check whether the user giving input with this database results to verify user is valid or not and if not valid after 3 times..blocked

Comment: If I understand your request correctly, you want to somehow log all attempts to 'guess' a username and if the user guesses incorrectly 3 times, then lock them out? If this is the case, you would do well to send or log information in addition to the username (such as a session_id) being sent so that you can 'count' this on the server side, otherwise the user can just clear anything on the browser side.  You could send and log a session ID and incorrect count against that. Once that count reaches 3, you just send a blocked response from the server and handle that on the browser side.

Comment: ok how can we alter this code ?

Comment: There are a couple of things that will need to be done. You will need to post a session_id if you have one. If not, you will need to create one in PHP and then post that. 
You will also need to create a table in your database in order to log the information. In your PHP script you will then need to check if the username exists and if not, log the session_id in the new table. The logic of the PHP script will then be - Check if the session-id is blocked. If not, check username exists, if not then log another failure in the table and if the username does exist, carry on with what it did before.

Comment: The problem with doing what you are trying to do on the client-side is that a simple page refresh will reset your count.

Comment: thank you for your idea...iam trying to make it

Comment: var d_name=prompt("username","");

    if(d_name != "")
        var d_password=prompt("password","");

document.cookie = "name="+d_name;
document.cookie = "password="+d_password;

alert(document.cookie);
    var attempt = document.getElementById("attempt").value;

    if(d_name != "" && d_password != "")
    {
        if (d_name+d_password==document.cookie[+name+]document.cookie[+password+]); 
        { what i did was just store name and password inside cookies and checked cookie values with variable values inside if condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211242/discussion-between-austin-and-o-genthe).